# Launch an app on iOS using taps

Tags: ios, widget

I would like to know if it is possible to launch an app on iOS that is currently in the back group using three taps for example ? Think of it as a short cut on a desktop app. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No!**
That is not possible. There is no way to open one specific app on some combination of touches.

You can however open other apps from your app using url schemes, but something like that is not supported across the entire OS and of course not supported on the springboard. ([see the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html))